# scikitlearn MLPRegression model conversion to TensorFlow Dnnregressor conversion

Tags: tensorflow

I implement custom Neural Network (prediction part only) based on ScikitLearn MLPRegressor model weights with sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler normalization of input features

Can I convert it DNNRegressor of TensorFlow or any other way that would allow me to implement it in python and execute in C#/C++ .
I would like to include sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler in the model such that I would be able to serialize it to pb file that would be executed from C++

Thanks
Sasha